# Android Button click

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I want to know if their is way to check if a button is clicked X times do something. For example i have a button in my android app and if a user clicks it more than 3 times i want to show an ad. The code for my project is below. I believe their is a way to implement it on my onlcicklistener but not sure how to go about it.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;


public class ClipAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private StartAppAd startAppAd;
   private GridActivity m_context;
   private Soundboard m_soundboard;
   private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;


public ClipAdapter(GridActivity c, Soundboard s) {
    m_context = c;
    startAppAd = new StartAppAd(m_context);
    m_soundboard = s;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )m_context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return m_soundboard.getSize();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return m_soundboard.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        final Clip c = m_soundboard.get(position);
        View rowView;

        if (c != null) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
            TextView tv =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            ImageButton button=(ImageButton)           rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            //Button button = new Button(m_context);
            //button.setHeight(24);
            tv.setText(c.getTitle());
            m_context.registerForContextMenu(button);
            button.setTag(c);
            //button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xffFFFFFF, 0xffFFFFFF));
            //button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    m_context.play(c.getResourceId());
                }
            });

            //return button;
            return rowView;
        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "No audio at position "
                + position);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

defina a variable like `buttonClickTimes` as `integer` and assign to `0`.
 Within your `onClickListener` method do your job and at the beginning of your `onClickListener` increment it like `buttonClickTimes++` and put an `if` statement in your `onClick` method

so your code should be like this:

```
Button button;
button.setOnClickListener(buttonClickHandler);
    View.OnClickListener buttonClickHandler= new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
             buttonClickTimes++;
          // do something when the button is clicked



           if(buttonClickTimes == 3) 
              {//show your ad}
        }
    };
```

EDIT: put `buttonClickTimes` at the beginning of your `onClick` method since you want to show ad when the button clicked 3 times.

Comment: Not in the main method (what is that even in android?). The `if` goes into the `onClick` method as well because that's what is executed.

Comment: @zapl I ment, in this activity by saying main. Sorry for misunderstanding.